# Make current post link's ID "current"

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress site and am pretty much finished, the only thing I can't seem to figure out is how to get WordPress to know I am on a certain post and set that link's ID to "current". Below is the code I have, and in the if statement in the '**a**' tag is some psuedo code for what I need done pretty much. Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
<ul>
    <?php query_posts(array( 'post_type'=>'project', 'posts_per_page' => 4));?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <li> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" <?php if(is_current_post()) { ?> id="current" <?php } ?>><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<?php
global $post;
$currentPostId = $post->ID;
?>
<ul>
    <?php query_posts(array('post_type'=>'project', 'posts_per_page'=>4)); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php $projectCurrentPostId = get_the_ID(); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" <?php if($currentPostId == $projectCurrentPostId) { ?> id="current" <?php } ?>>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$current_post_id = $post->ID;

<ul>
            <?php query_posts(array('post_type' => 'project', 'posts_per_page' => 4));?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" <?php if($wp_query->current_post->ID ==  $current_post_id) { ?> id="current" <?php } ?>><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the input, but it didn't work :(